# Can I Manage Data Distribution Among Devices Connected to my Android Hotspot?

Tags: applications, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, data-monitoring

I rely on my Android tablet's mobile data as a hotspot for both my work devices and other household members' devices. I'm looking for an app, method, or setting that allows me to control and manage the daily data transmitted to these connected devices via the hotspot. Specifically, I aim to prioritize data distribution to my work devices while regulating the data available to other connected devices.

Is there a method, application, or setting that provides fine-grained control over data distribution among devices connected to an Android hotspot? My objective is to establish daily data limits for individual devices, halting data transfer to a device once it reaches its assigned limit.